# Pasted linked Excel tables to Word

Tags: excel, ms-word

Anybody has any idea, why pasted linked tables are resized after word document is opened and external data from excel refreshed?

[image]

[image]

The line at the bottom of the table represents initial width of pasted table.
When table is firstly pasted the size of it is set to w:97% h:108%. Then when you open word document with table saved, it gets shrinked after data refresh, especially in width. If I doubleclick the table to open excel source file, then it gets resized again.

It is really frustrating and impossible to work with when you are building a catalog (word linked to excel pricelist).

Using Windows 7, Windows 8, Office 2007, 2010, 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the trick is pasting it with mouse (right click & paste, than choose "Keep source formatting and link to excel").

Even trickier is pasting it to a word table. To do that, first paste it outside the table, switch to the CodeView with Alt + F9, and than cut&paste the code of linked excel table somewhere inside the word table (press Alt + F9 to exit CodeView). This way linked table remains formated and linked.